# changing box2d body fixtures during an animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have read a few posts that confirmed that a b2body's shape can be destroyed and recreated though none of them showed how. Also I want to change the fixtures during my animation. Not during every frame change but only for the key frame changes. How do I synchronize the creation and destruction of the fixtures with the timing for the animation?

Comment: As you have read , B2Body's shape can be destroyed and recreated..What have you tried for destroying and recreating B2Body. Same thing is for B2Fixture. You have to destroy and recreate the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good decision to recreate your fixtures often. b2World will ignore your fixture if you recreate it every tick. It is mych simplier to use some common fixture (circle, box) and just rotate/move it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my answer to this question as it seems to be similar one.

[Re-creating fixtures for animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612965/updating-a-box2d-fixture-position-frame-by-frame-for-an-animation?answertab=active#tab-top)