# updating a box2d fixture position frame-by-frame for an animation

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

The sprites I am using in my game have complex shapes and animations. Also I'm only interested in setting contact listeners for certain parts of the sprite. I would like to set fixtures for the specific contact areas of interest. How can I keep moving body fixtures in the right positions as I change the sprite animations frame by frame?

Answer (score 1):

It`s not possible to change fixtures position. Only destroying and creating then again (but it will decrease performance).

Instead of it, you can create 2 separated bodies and get then together using joints. It will be the same behavior of 2 fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a right approach or not but for it doesn't make any performance issue, so you can try it.
First you have to destroy the current fixture of the body after saving its last position.

```
float body_x=Body.getPosition().x;
float body_y=Body.getPosition().y;

Body.destroyFixture(Body.getFixtureList().get(0));
```

And then you have to create a new fixture for that body like this

```
Body.createFixture(createFixturePart(
                body_x,
                body_y,
                Width,
                Height,
                Angle, 1, 1, 0, -1));
```

Here `createFixturePart` is my custumized function to create fixture of a body. You can have that while you create a body.And for the new fixture you can change the `Width`, `height` and `Angle` of the fixture according to your requirement. But don't re-create the fixture for every render cycle, instead change it only during the change of frame in the animation or whole animation.

`createFixturePart Method`

```
public FixtureDef createFixturePart(float x, float y, float width,
            float height, float angle, int mass, int density, int type,
            int groupIndex) {
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(width, height);
        shape.setAsBox(width / 2, height / 2, new Vector2(0, 0),
                (float) Math.toRadians(angle));
        MassData massData = new MassData();
        massData.mass = mass;


        bodyDef.position.y = y;
        bodyDef.position.x = x;

        Body body = worldbox.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.setMassData(massData);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = density;
        fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = (short) groupIndex;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 10;
        return fixtureDef;
    }
```

Comment: Better than destroying and recreating is having them all exists and disable collision on the ones that are not active. Much less performance intensive to change the ones not active to sensors. Also allows for checking things like if there is enough room to stand up and what not.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: how can I ensure that the timing is synchronized with that of the animation frame changes? Also I would really appreciate if you include the definition for `createFixturePart`.

Answer (score 0):

To change fixtures positions destory them, and create new fixtures at needed positions. But, I think, it is not good solution to change body fixtures, because it may corrupt simulation and decrease perfomance.

Comment: Can't I move the fixture positions to synchronize them with the animation without destroying and recreating them? that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: @IMustCode, No, box2d doesn't provide such interface.